# Trouble visualize GIS data with Geopandas.plot()

Tags: python, geopandas

I want to visualize the GIS data about Iran accidents in googlecolab, I have latitude, longitude, and death_count information but when I try to read it as Geopaandas data frame the plot function is not working correctly, May you please advise me on this issue, I have 3720 rows and 3 columns, and the result of visualization is attached as a link, thanks in advance for your help.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
df = pd.read_excel("/content/accidents98.xlsx")
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.longitude)و df.latitude))
gdf['death_count']] = gdf[['death_count']].fillna(value=0)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(20, 20))
ax.axis('off')
ax.set_title('accidents in Iran',
             fontdict={'fontsize': '15', 'fontweight' : '3'})
fig = gdf.plot(column='death_count', cmap='RdYlGn', linewidth=0.5, ax=ax, edgecolor='0.2',legend=True)
```

the input:
[image: input]

the output:
[image: output]

Comment: Those aren’t latitudes and longitudes. They look like they’re meters in some CRS. Read the geopandas guide to [managing projections](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/projections.html), then you’ll need to find out what the projection of your data is and transform it. There’s no way for us to diagnose this issue without a [mre]. Also, when editing your question, just go ahead and change the question to clarify it - don’t leave "edit”/update notes as you go. We can see the edit log if we want the history. But make sure your code reflects what you’re actually doing. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, your comments really helped I mistakenly searched for the error but the data is not correct, I find the shapefiles and work with that data. I'll remember your advise for the next question. have a good time.

Comment: no problem. for what it's worth, a lot of geospatial data looks something like that. but if it's valid data, it must be in some cartographic projection. so it's possible that wherever you got your data from, there is metadata showing a code, something like "EPSG:3857" or "+proj:CEA" or something like that. If you know the CRS, you can transform your data to plot correctly on the map. but without it, yeah it's hard to make sense of. good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `points_from_xy(df.latitude  , df.longitude)`. [`points_from_xy`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.points_from_xy.html) expects `(x, y)` not `(y, x)`. You need to switch the lat/lon order to lon, lat

Comment: Thanks a lot for your anwer dear Michael, I fixed what you mentioned but still get incorrect result with axes, would you please check the new output and advise me should I chenge the axes in deferent way?thanks again.